# How to build a quantum circuit representing the Ising Model?

Tags: programming, circuit-construction, machine-learning

Can someone explain to me how to build a quantum circuit representing the Ising Model? I just want to understand how to represent the Ising Model for the purposes of quantum state label classification.

Comment: Does this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07112 help?

Comment: A bit, but still in the dark.

Comment: What don't you understand about the paper I linked?

Comment: For example, if I have a U(\theta), where U is a resulting unitary matrix of a series of unitaries with distinct theta parameters, I want to understand what is the difference between measuring at every wire in the circuit and measure the energy vs measuring the wire of the line-out qubit. And for that matter, why Pauli-Y is important in measuring in the line-out qubit. 

In short: I am trying to understand quantum variation algorithms using Cirq and how to use the problem (Ising model) described as a circuit to find minimal energies?

Comment: Right now I am still unsure of how exactly I can take a hamiltonian and translate that statement into a circuit.

Comment: Which variant of the Ising model are you wanting? one-dimensional transverse Ising model?

Comment: I am using a 2d lattice with an external field present.